# Geometry of Balls and Cubes

Tags: geometry, multivariable-calculus, metric-spaces

I'm stuck on a detail of a proof (Sard's Theorem in Lee's ISM) that deals with the geometry of balls and cubes in Euclidean space. Here's the setup (I'll rename some of the variables from the proof to simplify them and isolate my question): We have a closed cube $E \subset \mathbb{R}^m$ of side length $R$ on which a function $F : E \to \mathbb{R^n}$ is defined. We also know that there is a point $a \in E$ such that for all $x \in E$, $|F(x) - F(a)| \leq A|x - a|^{k}$ for some fixed real $A \geq 0$ and $k \in \mathbb{Z}^+$. It is claimed that $F(E)$ is contained within a ball of radius $AR^k$.

I can certainly see that $F(E)$ is contained in a ball of radius $Am^{k/2}R^k$, because $|x - a| \leq \sqrt{m}R$ for $x \in E$. But I can't improve this radius to what's given in the proof. What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're not missing anything. This is just a stupid mistake. I've added a correction to my [online list](https://sites.math.washington.edu/~lee/Books/ISM/).